# numpy and pil reshape arrays

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

pil to numpy conversion leads to arrays like:

```
a = array([ [[r,g,b],[r,g,b].....[r,g,b],[r,g,b]]  ,  [[r,g,b],[r,g,b.....]] , int8)
```

triplets of rgb values; within rows so :

```
a[0] = [[r,g,b],[r,g,b].....[r,g,b],[r,g,b]] = first row
```

is there a quick way to convert such triplets numpy arrays back and ford to
(well especialy back..)

```
a = [[rrrr],[rrrrr],[rrrrr],.... [bbbbb],[bbbbbb],[bbbbbb]...,[ggggg],[ggg],[ggg]]
```

**or**

like

```
a=[[rrr],[rrrrr],[....    ...]] **or** aa = [rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr..]

b=[[bbb],[bbbbb],[....    ...]]**or** bb = [bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb..]

c=[[ggg],[ggggg],[....      .]] **or** cc = [ggggggggggggggggggggggggg..]
```

My problem I have a format like aa bb cc and know the image size 640x480 how to get it fast into pill format as below

```
a = array([ [[r,g,b],[r,g,b].....[r,g,b],[r,g,b]]  ,  [[r,g,b],[r,g,b.....]] , int8)
```

Answer (score 4):

Does `a.T` give you what you want?

I'm assuming you've created your array using numpy's `asarray` function.

```
import Image, numpy
im = Image.open('test.png')
a = numpy.asarray(im)
R,G,B,A = a.T
```

The above will give you 4 separate 2D arrays, one for each band.

Answer (score 0):

ahum so answers work, i can type them... well

Well actually i'm not using asarray because i'm working in opposite direction (asarry creates triplets) i have data in the form of channels. so red green and blue; my data looks like this
a = [ r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r,r   ...]
where r are all the redvalues in a one dimensional array, in fact this channel-image is red.

b = all bleu ,and c is all green.
so the format i have is not in triplets.
I wonder if there is a quick combine function to generate such triplets. in fact Pil uses arrays inside arrays, i was looking at pil but if pygame or something else can show me a pick from channels is ok PIL is not a requirement; but it seams all formats use triplets; while my data doesnt contain it. Since Numpy is the most important array library as far as i know, i wonder if it can do such array operations,

its sad i cannot draw here to explain what i want i have like a, b and c

a = [123123123132]

b = [989898389398]

c = [343434343434]

d[a,b,c] =  a[] + b[] + c[]   >>> this isnt python code this is my thinking code

so d becomes d[[a,b,c],[a,b,c],[a,b,c], ...   ..]

and d[0] = [1,9,3]